# Error 40101 when retrieving Avro schema in kafka-avro-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

The following error appears when attempting to use Confluent Platform CLI tools to read messages from Kafka.

```
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960189+0100] [2023-01-17 18:00:14,957] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:105)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960210+0100] org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 119
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960230+0100] Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 40101
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960249+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:170)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960272+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:188)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960293+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:330)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960312+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:323)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960332+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:63)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960353+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndID(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:118)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960372+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:121)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960391+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:92)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960412+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:120)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960431+0100]   at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:112)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960449+0100]   at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:137)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960468+0100]   at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:75)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960487+0100]   at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:50)
[2023-01-17T18:00:14.960506+0100]   at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

I am using Kafka 3.2 (both client and server), with a Karapace schema registry by Aiven. I can query the schema registry manually using `curl` by including the credentials in the URL:

```
(base) me@my-laptop:~$ curl https://$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD@$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT/subjects
["my-topic-" <redacted>
```

Or as basic auth in a header:

```
(base) me@my-laptop:~$ curl -u "$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" https://$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT/subjects
["my-topic-" <redacted>
```

The error seems to happen when the credentials are not passed to the schema registry:

```
(base) me@my-laptop:~$ curl https://$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT/subjects
{"error_code": 40101, "message": "Unauthorized"}
```

According to official docs for `kafka-avro-console-consumer`, I can use the authentication source `URL` or `USER_INFO`, and it should pass those credentials to the schema registry. This does not work, and causes the above error.

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer \
          --bootstrap-server $KAFKA_HOST:$KAFKA_PORT \
          --consumer.config /home/guido/.tls/kafka/client-tls.properties \
          --property schema.registry.url=https://$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD@$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST:$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT \
          --property basic.auth.credentials.source=URL \
          --topic my-topic
```

I've tried every combination I can think of, with URL, USER_INFO, separate credentials, prefixed with `schema.registry` and without, but all lead to the same error. When I use the regular `kafka-console-consumer.sh` the same settings work, but I see the Kafka messages as a byte stream, rather than the deserialized Avro message that I'm looking for.

EDIT: it appears that java.net.HttpURLConnection is the problem. It strips credendtials from the URL, and the version of schema-registry-client packaged with Confluent Platform does not support any other version of Basic Authentication yet.

```
import java.net.URL
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class ExampleTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  
  behavior.of("Example")

  it should "work" in {
    val url = "https://username:p4ssw0rd@kafka.example.com:12345"

    val connection = new URL(url).openConnection()

    noException shouldBe thrownBy {
      connection.getInputStream
    }
  }
}
```

The test fails

Comment: Edit: the tag `confluent-platform` was removed from the question. I re-added it because the tool `kafka-avro-console-consumer` is part of Confluent Platform.

Comment: I found that we can edit `/etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties` to see an additional log line. The additional logging shows that the credentials are passed to schema registry in the URL, I can copy that URL and use it in curl (200 OK), but still in the CLI client, a 40101 error occurs.

Comment: And I removed again because the script is actually part of `schema-registry` repo.

Comment: @OneCricketeer The script is installed by calling `apt-get install confluent-platform`. The first documentation page of Confluent Platform is where we find documentation for this tool (https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/quickstart.html). Anyone looking for it is likely to search by those labels.
Imo this type of moderation serves noone and only makes the question less visible. But since my problem is solved I'll leave it be...

Comment: Regardless, the script itself is [part of the registry repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/master/bin). The APT package is a meta-package of all confluent components, including the registry, and your question is really only about the Registry interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. There were three causes for my problem.

1. I had an old version of Confluent Platform installed, namely `confluent-platform-2.11`. This version did not yet support any schema registry authentication, beyond username and password in the URL.
2. I thought I had the latest version already (3.3.x) but that's actually the latest version of Kafka, not the latest version of Confluent Platform.
3. Java's default web request implementation, `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`, does not support credentials in the URL. They are stripped before making the request, despite the URL correctly containing the credentials.

The correct solution was to upgrade to a later version of Confluent Platform.

See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#configure-cp